# Extending GeoTIFF extent with node

Tags: geotiff-tiff, node-gdal

I am using node-gdal package for manipulating data from geotiff files.
Origin file was ASCII XYZ GRID .txt file.
I managed to divide whole area into same-size regions by manipulating ASCII XYZ GRID files.
I created .tif's with using gdal_translate.
So I ended with x .tif files.

gdal_translate creates geotiffs with extent which fit to the smallest found value of X and Y.
Let's say I want my area's extent to start with [133000, 654300].
But in XYZ file coords from [133000, 654300] to [134000, 655300] don't contain any data.

To illustrate, here is a pic.

[image]

What I want to get, is an extent with orange color(I know the coordinates of extent I want to achieve). What I get is a geotiff with extent determined by red color.

How can I broaden extent of geotiff file to a selected value with use of node-gdal?